# Submitting multiple forms with Javascript (no refresh)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run this in Chrome/Firefox Console but not having any luck.

```
(function(d) {
  var form = d.getElementsByTagName('form');
  var i = form.length;

  while (i--) {

    form[i].addEventListener("submit", function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
    }, false);

    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "http://example.com/", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send("media_id=" + form[i].elements["media_id"].value);

  }
})(this.document);
```

Can anyone spot any problems with it? Thanks

EDIT:
I have fixed the problem. Thanks @Niklas

Comment: I see you adding an event listener, but you aren't submitting the form here.

Comment: jquery ajax in browser console?

Comment: Two important questions:  1. What do you expect this script to do?  2.  What is actually happening?

Comment: 1. As the subject states "Submitting multiple forms with Javascript (no refresh)" - I want it to submit all the forms on the page.
2. Nothing.
I am writing something now to hit the submit buttons. Not sure if it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are preventing the form submissions but not actually doing anything to send them. You'd presumably want to add some ajax to send the data.